# TwitterAPI "Invalid or expired token."

Tags: python, twitter, oauth-2.0

I'm writing a simple script in python to read the members of a Twitter list.

The code:

```
TW_CONSUMER_KEY = '<consumer key>'
TW_CONSUMER_SECRET = '<consumer secret>'
TW_ACCESS_TOKEN = '<access token>'
TW_ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET = '<token secret>'

twapi = TwitterAPI(TW_CONSUMER_KEY, TW_CONSUMER_SECRET, TW_ACCESS_TOKEN, TW_ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET)

def list_members(slug, owner_screen_name, limit=1e10):
    """See https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/lists/members"""
    cursor = -1
    members = []
    try:
        response = twapi.request('lists/members', {'slug': slug, 'owner_screen_name': owner_screen_name, 'cursor': cursor, 'count': 5000})
        if response.status_code in [88, 130, 420, 429]:  # rate limit
            sys.stderr.write('Error for %s/%s: %s\nSleeping for 5 minutes...\n' % (owner_screen_name, slug, response.text))
            time.sleep(301)
        elif response.status_code != 200:
            sys.stderr.write('Skipping bad query: %s\n' % response.text)
            return members
        else:
            items = [r['screen_name'] for r in response if 'screen_name' in r]
            return items
    except Exception as e:
        sys.stderr.write('Error: %s\nskipping...\n' % e)
        return members
    return members
```

This code raises the error:

```
Skipping bad query: {"errors":[{"code":89,"message":"Invalid or expired token."}]}
```

I've renewed the token and consumer keys, even if the documentation says they don't expire, but to no avail.

Can something be done about this issue? Is the TwitterAPI call correct?

Comment: Did you sign in with twitter to get the access token and the access token secret? Did you use the access token from the response to /oauth/access_token, and not the one from the request? https://dev.twitter.com/web/sign-in/implementing

Comment: I used your exact code with my tokens and it worked fine. Try regenerating your access tokens.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine, but you should manage your app on Twitter and change the permissions to "Read, Write and Direct Message".